# Could not click on link by name when reading from xls sheet in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

```
<td>
<a href="store.aspx?action=view&id=129">4999 AL test store 1 BCCAL, AL</a> </td>
```

code works if i use direct link name:

```
String a = "test store 1";
driver.findElement(By.linkText(a)).click();
```

if i use the store name from xls sheet

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText(xlstore)).click();
```

displays error unable to find the element

Comment: Can you print out what the variable xlstore variable returns before clicking and let us know??

Comment: What does it say?? I am thinking it might be an issue with illegal spaces